# How to order by same column 2x?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get last 3 records of a table and put them in ascending order.

The following query will return last 3 records of table, but it won't sort them.

```
select column_1, column_2 from table_name order by id desc limit 3
```

Is there a way to sort these records also, without using a subquery?

I tried

```
select column_1, column_2 from table_name order by id desc, id asc limit 3
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: why not with subquery ? it will be easy and no issue performance because only 3 records...

Answer (score 4):

In my view I don't think that any other way without sub query will make it easily

Try below :

```
SELECT a.* from 
(SELECT column_1, column_2 FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3) as a
ORDER BY a.id ASC
```

subquery is not a bad idea in this situation where you using it with `limit`.

Comment: You insist on this version which has 2 errors. MySQL will complain that there is no alias for the subquery and `ORDER BY id` cannot find any `id`.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use PDO:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM your-table ORDER BY date DESC Limit 3');
```

Comment: -1: Simply adding perl code around the query isn't an answer. If you mean to sort them on the client side, you should say so, and you should show the code that sorts them.

Comment: It's `PHP` as the question is tagged. It's a PDO query sample, showing the PDO code is irrelevant in this case.

Comment: Yeah, the PHP tag is wrong -- there's nothing PHP specific about this question, and I'm sure that adding this PDO code didn't bring the asker any closer to the right answer.